# Serving a.html from apache while requesting b.html

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I'm creating a `nginx reverse proxy` to apache. Apache runs on port `8080` and nginx on `80`.

I hope to achieve the following;

When I request the page `http://server/test.html` it should be proxyed to `http://server:8080/unknown.html`

Later on I'll do some `eval` stuff on the pages and redirect the users to the right pages, but I can't even get this to work. I get the `test.html` back as response all the time.

My `nginx` config:

```
server {
        listen   80;

        root /var/www/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
               # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.html$ {

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;

                #rewrite ^/unknown.html;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1/test.html http://127.0.0.1:8080/unknown.html;
         }

         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

I have zero experience yet, but I'm eager to learn how to get this working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the `proxy_redirect` directive is the opposite of what you need. It is only used to rewrite the `Location` response headers in 3xx responses from upstream. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for details.

You can use a `rewrite ... break` statement within the location block that performs the `proxy_pass`, for example:

```
location ... {
    rewrite ^/test.html$ /unknown.html break;
    proxy_pass ...;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.